# Rails function or method like PHP date()

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

So i've date from database like '2014-03-10 12:43:00'. I'v tried to find some answer for me, but i have no results.
In PHP i can do like this:

```
echo date('d/m/Y', strtotime(here my variable with date))
```

What can i use on rails ? 
I'v tried to do like this:

```
%= Date.strptime(call.datetime, '%d-%m-%Y %H:%i') %>
```

But i see error:
no implicit conversion of ActiveSupport::TimeWithZone into String

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking for [strftime](http://apidock.com/ruby/Date/strftime), not [strptime](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/date/rdoc/DateTime.html#method-c-strptime).

```
<%= @date_variable.strftime('%d-%m-%Y %H:%M')
```

Note the %i you have doesn't seem to match up, check the docs to make sure you have the right format string.

Answer (score 1):

This is my solution:

```
<%= call.datetime.strftime('%m/%d/%Y') %>
```

Comment: Please, add more explaination to your solution. It may be obvious, but just a code snippet is not enough.

Comment: Now i use strftime() method. I pass format of data and it's work fine